# Merge DataFrames based on iindex applying specific function for resulting columns

Tags: python, concatenation, quantile

I have a list of large DataFrames, e.g.

```
N=100000
data = [pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2*N).reshape(N,2), columns = ['foo','bar']) for _ in range(100)]
```

and want to compute their quarantines, for example:

```
>>> pd.concat(data).quantile([.1,.3,.6,.9])
          foo       bar
0.1  0.100087  0.100087
0.3  0.300140  0.299953
0.6  0.600156  0.600022
0.9  0.900219  0.899880
```

My problem is that the concatenation takes some time and then quantiles are computed on the big resulting DataFrame. I was wondering if there is a way to do this without having to compose the concatenation.

Comment: So you want to calculate the quantile for each data frame in the list separately?

Comment: No, I would like to compute what I am now doing, but without having to concat... Not sure how easy it is since computing quantiles (naively??)  would mean you need to sort the data, but if that is not the case (e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10539/compute-approximate-quantiles-for-a-stream-of-integers-using-moments ???) Then there could be a function that would go through each of the dataframes and then output the total quantiles? - Or maybe this can only be done for approximations, in which case I ll stick to concat for now...